# jQuery: Increase padding top by +x pxs

Tags: jquery

With jQuery, how can I find all locations where a specific padding-top value is applied and then increase it from its existing value?

I looked at selectors and I could not find such a thing.

Comment: Don't do this through jQuery or JavaScript use css.

Comment: This will be very inefficient.  Why do you want to do this?  Is there no better way to narrow down which elements should be affected?

Comment: I need this in order to maximize the similarity between browsers. Firefox (Gecko) and Chrome+Safari (Webkit) render certain gaps differently. Also Firefox and Safari render fonts a bit bolder than Chrome, and the list goes on and on. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean to search the whole DOM? It's *quite* inefficient:

```
$('*').each(function() {

    var padTop = $(this).css('padding-top'); // get the padding
    if (padTop > 0)
        $(this).css('padding-top', padTop + x); // add x to it if more than 0

});
```

It seems like `each()` is better than `filter()` because we can filter by padding and increase it in the same scope. It's strongly adviseable to replace `'*'` with the most specific selector you can afford to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a function that checks for a specific padding on elements?

Might be a tad slow statement though...

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to apply this only to a particular type of element (ex: `div`s only?). In that case you could do something like @Jeroen mentioned:

```
$('div').filter(function() { return this.style.paddingTop == "2px"; }) // use your specific padding value.
```